# Laravel 5: To cache or use sessions for building a site-wide banner?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a feature into a Laravel 5 app that will allow you to set the content of a status banner that will display across the top of the page. We will be using this banner both to display page-specific things (status messages, etc) and site-wide announcements (every user sees the same thing, banner stays the same for awhile).

Right now, I've implemented this by using Laravel sessions to allow banners to be added by calling a helper method from any controller or middleware:

```
    // Call set_banner from in a controller or middleware (for persistent banners)
function set_banner($banner_text, $banner_class, $banner_persistant=false, $replace=false)
{
    $banners = session()->get('banners', []);

    // Create new banner
    $banner = [
            'text' => $banner_text,
            'type' => $banner_class,
            'persistent' => $banner_persistant
            ];

    // Only put banner in array if it's not already there
    if( !in_array($banner, $banners) ) {
        // Either override existing banners, or add to queue
        if( !$replace ) session()->push('banners', $banner);
        else session()->put('banners', [$banner]);
    }
}

// Called by default in the master.blade.php template
function get_banners()
{
    $banners = session()->pull('banners', Array());
    foreach( $banners as $banner ) {
        // Print out each banner
        print '<div class="col-md-12"><div class="text-center alert alert-block alert-'.$banner['type'].'">';
        print $banner['text'];
        print '</div></div>';

        // Push back into the session if banner is marked as persistent
        if ( $banner['persistent'] ) session()->push( 'banners', $banner );
    }
}
```

Banners are created in controllers or middleware like this:

```
set_banner("<b>Note:</b> This is a sample persistant-scope banner set in a controller", "success", true);
```

Is there a better way to accomplish storing both page-level and site-wide banners? My concerns is that hitting the session on every pageload may be inefficient, especially for banners that won't be changing for long periods of time. Will this approach mess with Laravel's cache, etc?

Answer (score 0):

As you said the banners do not change that often. Hence for me i would implement it using Cache. This improves performance since we need only one use to have the banners cached. And for the rest its retrieved faster from the Cache rather Session.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have to change code to change the banner of a given page?
I would suggest instead creating a "pages" package, where each page route name is entered into a database.

From there, from your page service provider you get Page::getModel()->banner_text or something similar.
The method would look for a db result matching the current route name with a result within db.

when a controller method is triggered you simply call
Page::getBannerText()

That method will pull the current route name, pull the page result related to that page if it exists or create it if it does not exist (easy way to get everything). You cache the db query result for X hours, days or whatever so whenever someone else makes a call, you don't even need to deal with any storage on client side.

This allows you to modify the value from a db fascet. Its the more "proper" way to do it.